# jackknife paired t-test in R

Tags: r, resampling

Consider the following dummy data:

```
x <- rnorm(15,mean = 3,sd = 1)
y <- rnorm(15,mean = 3,sd = 1)
xy <- c(x,y)
factor <- c(rep('A',15),rep('B',15))

df1 <- data.frame(xy,factor)
df1$PAIR_IDENTIFIER <- 1:15
```

Now, we want to test if the means are different between the `factor==A` and `factor==B`. So we implement a paired t-test

```
paired_t_test <- t.test(xy ~ factor, df1, paired = T)
paired_t_test$p.value
```

**Now we want to extend on this by using a jackknife resample**

That is we leave one pair (`PAIR_IDENTIFIER`) and re-run the t-test. We want to re-run the test 15-1 times.

I have tried to implement the `jackknife` function from the [bootstrap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bootstrap/bootstrap.pdf) library

```
library(bootstrap)

n <- length(df1$xy)

theta <- function(x,df1){ t.test(xy ~ factor, df1, paired = T)}
results <- jackknife(1:n,theta,df1)
```

But I am not sure how to write the function to remove a `PAIR_IDENTIFIER` for each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. There's really no need to remove that variable, t-test will only use what's specified in the formula.

```
theta.fun <- function(x, mydata) {
     t.test(xy ~ factor, 
           data = mydata[mydata$PAIR_IDENTIFIER %in% x, ], 
           paired = T)$p.value
}

jackknife(x = 1:15, theta = theta.fun, mydata = df1)

$jack.se
[1] 0.5257458

$jack.bias
[1] 0.4501173

$jack.values
 [1] 0.4064047 0.1164558 0.6187378 0.2853089 0.5913767 0.3906702 0.3528575 0.5142996 0.2430837 0.5590809 0.5015720 0.6029110 0.3881225
[14] 0.5223167 0.3734025

$call
jackknife(x = 1:15, theta = theta.fun, mydata = df1)
```